# What could cause this error: Uncaught TypeError: r.clamp is not a function?

Tags: javascript, encryption, base64

I'm trying to use the following funciton to encrypt a Base64 encoded string using the **AES-256-CFB** algorithm, and when I try to encode the result back to Base64 it casues the following error: **Uncaught TypeError: r.clamp is not a function**

```js
function (base64EncodedString, password) {
    let iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(256 / 16);

    let salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex).substr(0, 16));

    let key = CryptoJS.EvpKDF(password, CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(salt), { keySize: 256 / 32 });

    let nonEncryptedString = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(base64EncodedString);

    let cipher = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({ ciphertext: nonEncryptedString , iv: iv, salt: salt, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding,});
    
    let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(cipher, key, {mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding, iv: iv});
        
    let ecrytpedBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted);
    
    return ecrytpedBase64;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're passing the encrypted variable (of type CipherParams) to the stringify function, which expects a WordArray (your iv variable).

```
CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted); // TypeError: r.clamp is not a function
CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(iv); // Ok
```

Comment: How could I access the encrypted value?

Comment: I think for your purpose you could probably do something like this:
`let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(nonEncryptedString, key, {
    iv,
    salt,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding,
  });

  console.log(encrypted.toString());`